# Can the document receiver see the version history of an attached Word document in the email?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, email

The Word document was in my OneDrive and I can see the version history. But when I attach it to the email (its an attachment not sending a shared link etc), then the person who receives it cannot see the version history can they?

The versions are not stored in the Word document is it? So, if it's not stored in the file itself, then no body can see the versions, right?

They don't have credentials to access/sign in to my OneDrive account. Can they see the version history? I already deleted tracked changes. But didn't delete version history.

Comment: This is painful for you, I'm sure. To use the tools available in the Windows version, you need to edit in the Windows version. You might be able to do this if prepared to edit the XML of a document. (I would not, myself.) The Windows and Mac versions are not equivalent even though they can edit the same files.  If, in a document **copy** you accept all changes and turn off track changes and then copy the content into a new document which you transmit, that new document should be free of the version history.

Comment: The OneDrive version history is different from the document's revision history. As far as I know the OneDrive version history is not stored in the document, itself.

Comment: OneDrive history is just versioning of the file itself; any file not just a Word file. The version history in the Word document is contained within the Word file itself. This might seem confusing but for anyone who doesn’t use OneDrive, Word version history contained in the file itself is useful to go back to a previous version. So long story short, to remove the history of a Word file you need to somehow clear the history from the Word file itself.

Answer (score 0):

> (A) But when I attach it to the email (its an attachment not sending a
> shared link etc), then the persons who receives it cannot see the
> version history can they?
>
> (B) The versions are not stored in the word document is it?
>
> So, if it's not stored in the file itself, then no body can see the
> versions, right?

**(A)** Revision History IS stored in the document.

**(B)** Users receiving the document as attachment can see the revision history.

Open the attachment in Word.  Then Word Menu, and Info shows the revision history.

I tested this on an attachment I received from another person with Word 365, but the same thing works in prior versions.

Your question asks "Can the document receiver see the revision history?"  - Yes they can.

If for whatever reason you wish Revision History not to be seen, then it needs to be removed by the tools that are available to remove the history.

Comment: thanks for the clear answers, I made a copy of the file (not text copy, I made a copy of the file), now the `"File -> Browse Version History"` is disabled in the new copied file. May be the version history does not transfer to the copied file? or should I still be concerned although it's disabled?.

Comment: I do not think copying a file normally deletes File Revision history. That does not happen here. Try "Document Inspector" as Harry pointed to.  For Tracking Marks,   On the Review tab, go to Tracking.  In the Track Changes drop-down list, select Off.

Comment: Please see the comment I have made under harry's comment. The `File > Info > Check for Issues > Inspect Document` does not exist in my word software, then how can I follow something that does not exist? my version is: `Microsoft word for mac, version 16.56 - Microsoft 365 subscription`

Comment: There is no such Info item under files on Word for Mac 365.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Document Inspector to remove hidden data:

- Open the document and click menu
  *File > Info > Check for Issues > Inspect Document*
- The Word Document Inspection window opens up
- Click "Remove All" next to the items that you wish to delete,
  for example all comments, revisions, versions and annotations
- Save the document, and it will no longer contain the items you have removed.

Comment: I'm on mac, I can't see the "info" in the file menu.

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to the OneDrive version history, rather than the Word revision history? I believe that the OneDrive version history is only visible to the owner (you).

Comment: no, I'm referring to any kind of history that can track changes I have made from creation of the file. And I can't see the "info" in the file menu that you're mentioning

Comment: Which Word version are you using?

Comment: `Microsoft word for mac, version 16.56` - `Microsoft 365 subscription`

Comment: Could you please add to your post a screenshot of the File menu in Word? I don't have a Mac to test on.

Comment: @harrymc, the mac version does not have a File menu. It has the Word menu which is somewhat equivalent. It has some of the features/quirks of the menu version of Word for Windows. It does not have File > Options, but does have Word > Preferences. It does not have the document inspector.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon the `File` menu does exist in `mac version`, but it does not have any `File > Info > Check for Issues > Inspect Document`

Comment: I found [an answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/word-for-mac-2016-document-inspector-removing/9fe7a740-d6d6-4efe-b0be-67ccca9aad51?auth=1) on the internet: "It's still there, but has been relocated: Go to Tools> Protect Document or click the Protect Document button on the Review tab. You'll see it at the bottom of the dialog window". And another one: "Click Review>Protect>Protect document>Under 'Privacy' tick 'Remove personal information from this file on save'".

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up doing following:

1. Downloading a copy online (onedrive or teams etc.)
2. Removed local file.
3. Renamed online file and placed it in folder.

I noticed that if you replaced the file with a file with the same name the history magically was remembered... So nuke the old and make sure the reference between the files are all gone (renaming new file). Stupid shit Microsoft. Why would they leave such a critical feature out for Mac users.